# Help with with my function for wordpress

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields, text, labels

i have a question if i wanted to hide the title if nothing is entered how can i achive this with this fuction i would be greatful for any help

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_custom_fuction');

function my_custom_fuction() { 
echo 'Pack Quantity: ' . get_field('pack_quantity');
echo'
';
echo 'items per: ' . get_field('per_pack');

with pack quantity, items per being my title

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the `get_field()` comes up empty by doing

```
if ( get_field('pack_quantity') ) {
     //Your code
}
```

So something like this should work if you just need to check one of the fields.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_custom_fuction');

function my_custom_fuction() {

    if ( get_field('pack_quantity') ) { //Change this for which one you need to check
        echo 'Pack Quantity: ' . get_field('pack_quantity');
        echo''; 
        echo 'items per: ' . get_field('per_pack');
    }
}
```

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/hiding-empty-fields/

Comment: Pack Quantity is now hidden if no input thats great but now when i input example  ( 2pc set ) the other empty field labels shows i only want to show the ones i input  planning on add more custom fields along the way if i can get this to work thank you so much for taking the time to reply

Comment: Which field does "2pc set" belong to? `'per_pack'`?

Comment: 2pc set belong to Pack Quantity( how many pcs in the pack ) then items per = packs per box

Comment: <?php
    $fields = get_field_objects(); // I changed from get_fields()
    if( $fields ): ?>
      <ul>
        <?php
            // I changed $value to $field (i.e. the variable name)
            foreach( $fields as $name => $field ):
                if (stripos($name, 'isbn') !== false) : ?>
                    <li><b><?php echo $field['label']; ?></b> <?php echo $field['value']; ?></li>
                <?php endif;
            endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
this works a treat in php  but would like it in a function so i can add to product summery